# Reporting Errors in a multi-threaded Java-based Application

Tags: java, multithreading, error-handling

I currently develop a Java-based multi-threaded application which provides a GUI and accesses a service through the network.

Are there any patterns, best practices, libraries, frameworks or APIs for reporting errors in a Java-based system?

Comment: "Reporting Errors in a multi-threaded java based Application " Can you please elaborate little bit more .do you really need multithreaded   Application.

Comment: I see you're a new user, so it is probably worth reading the FAQ.  In particular http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask which describes the sort of questions that can't be asked on SO.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` which is used for handling errors in Threads.

```
Thread t = new Thread(task);

// add exception handler
t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    // do exception handling
  }
});

t.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your `Task Tracker` which is nothing an implementation of Observer DesignPatter.

```
public class TaskTracker {
private final List<ErrorListener> listeners = new ArrayList<ErrorListener>();

public Runnable wrap(final Runnable r) {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try { r.run(); }
            catch (Throwable t) {
                for (ErrorListener el : listeners)
                    el.error(t, this);
            }
        }
    };
}

public void addListener(ErrorListener el) { listeners.add(el); }

public void removeListener(ErrorListener el) { listeners.remove(el); }

public static interface ErrorListener {
    void error(Throwable t, Runnable r);
}
}
```